# Path of .keystore file for cordova signed apk with build.json

Tags: cordova, ionic3, apk, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I have a hybrid application developed with cordova.  Each time when I want to create signed apk,  I have to do the following procedures.

1. Do "cordova prepare" to install the plugins and platforms
2. $ cordova build android --release --buildConfig to create apk

I have build.json and app.keystore file in root of the cordova.
When I do $ cordova build android --release --buildConfig it is looking for app.keystore file inside android folder.  I don't want to manually copy paste the app.keystore file into android folder. How can we change the path of the keystore file while building the project itself or move the app.keystore file while doing build.  Thanks in advance

My build.json

```
{
  "android": {
      "debug": {
          "keystore": "../app.keystore",
          "storePassword": "united",
          "alias": "appreleasedemoalias",
          "password" : "*****",
          "keystoreType": "jks"
      },
      "release": {
          "keystore": "../app.keystore",
          "storePassword": "united",
          "alias": "appreleasedemoalias",
          "password" : "****",
          "keystoreType": "jks"
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are about [three](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#signing-an-app) possibilities to configure cordova to sign a apk.

1. Using Flags
2. Using build.json
3. Using Gradle

For configuration with build.json you could change the value of keystore to set the path of the keystore file.

```
{
"android": {
  "debug": {
      "keystore": "../../../../../secretsFolder/app.keystore",
      "storePassword": "united",
      "alias": "appreleasedemoalias",
      "password" : "*****",
      "keystoreType": "jks"
  },
  "release": {
      "keystore": "../app.keystore",
      "storePassword": "united",
      "alias": "appreleasedemoalias",
      "password" : "****",
      "keystoreType": "jks"
  }
}
}
```

Works with relative and absolute paths.